# jQuery .off() not removing handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically loaded button created when the document loads. After this, I attach a click handler to this button. When I try to remove the handler with `.off()`, it does not work.

This snippet creates the click handler and removes it. However, when I click the button, the function `StartMash` still executes.

```
$(document).on("click", "#mash-idle-start", StartMash);
$("#mash-idle-start").off();
```

Obviously this is not the functionality I am trying to achieve, but the problem persists through this simple example

Comment: It would be better if you gave it a namespace. `$(document).on("click.idleClick", "#mash-idle-start"...` and `$(document).off("click.idleClick")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because the event handler is not attached to `#mash-idle-start`, it is attached to `document` so

```
$(document).off("click", "#mash-idle-start", StartMash);
```

or

```
$(document).off("click", "#mash-idle-start");
```

Note: When working with event unbinding, try to use [event namespaces](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) as you will have more control over which handlers are removed.

Comment: I was running into a similar issue using `$('body').on('click tap', functionName)` and trying to unbind with `$('body').off('click tap', functionName)`. @ArunPJohny's recommendation to use [event namespaces](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) solved my problem. I instead used: `$('body').on('click.nameSpace tap.nameSpace', functionName)` and to unbind: `$('body').off('click.nameSpace tap.nameSpace')`. Worked like a charm. Answer up voted.